# Java - the constructor is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, super

I have an abstract class GeometricObject, which is extended by a base class Rectangle. In the superclass, I have two constructors provided:

```
  public abstract class GeometricObject {
  private String color = "white";
  private boolean filled;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  /** Construct a default geometric object */
  protected GeometricObject() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  /** Construct a geometric object with color and filled value */
  protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
  }
```

In the rectangle class, I've created another constructor, which is supposed to invoke the GeometricObject arguments constructor. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's the proper way to give values for "color" and "filled" for a Rectangle object.

```
public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Rectangle>{
  private double width;
  private double height;

  public Rectangle() {
  }

  **public Rectangle(double width, double height, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }**
```

However, Eclipse gives me the following error next to the super(color,filled) statement:
"The constructor GeometricObject(String, boolean) is undefined"

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems fine here - http://ideone.com/msFeyz.  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Incredible. After your comments, I've added a new test class and created an instance using the constructor, and suddenly the error disappeared. Mysterious IDE... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Constructor call looks fine, I have tried in Eclipse and it compiles without any error. However, as Rectangle class implements Comparable, we need to override `compareTo` method as shown below:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Rectangle o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0; //should be replaced by comparison logic
}
```

Comment: I removed the comparable method just for simplicity, thanks for mentioning it! After your comments, I've added a new test class and created an instance using the constructor, and suddenly the error disappeared. Mysterious IDE... Thanks!